# Is time quantized?

Tags: time

Is there a smallest possible duration? Is there some minimum duration by which some causality can occur? Perhaps a possible answer would be the time it takes for light (max velocity) to traverse the plank length (smallest distance). If that makes any sense at all can this "duration" be described in unitless terms?